# RXJS to synchronise a network call

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

Our ionic app calls a particular web service frequently and the server throws errors when same call is made in parallel.

We want to make sure the calls are synchronized. How to achieve this in RXJS?

```
Observers(View1..n)=>Observable(User)=={apply control here?}==>NetworkCall(getUser())
```

Comment: `.concatMap` will make sure all the requests are sequential

Answer (score 1):

### Use concat Map for sequential calls

concatMap(): Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output Observable, in a serialized fashion waiting for each one to complete before merging the next

```
SendMsg(msgs: string[]) {

            msgs.map(msg=> this.SendMsgService.({setail: msg.description, userId: msguser}));
            from(msgCalls)  
                .pipe(
                    concatMap(res => res), 
                ).subscribe(() => { });
}
```